# How to get Yocto SRC_URI revision number?

Tags: git, yocto, revision

In yocto recipe I fetch from git repo and build package, but I am interested in GIT revision number which yocto used to build package.
How I can get it? Does SRCREV and SRCPV can help? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As the manual says:](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html)

> Finally, for those recipes fetched from a version control system (e.g., Git), a file exists that lists source revisions that are specified in the recipe and lists the actual revisions used during the build. Listed and actual revisions might differ when `SRCREV` is set to `${AUTOREV}`. Here is an example assuming `buildhistory/packages/qemux86-poky-linux/linux-yocto/latest_srcrev`):[...]

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

Comment: Thanks it helped :-)

Comment: to be more precise, can you please also tell that how I can get recipes revision numbers from image built with yocto?

Comment: If I'm getting you, you can show current workbuild recipes using `bitbake -s` command.